# In sitecore How to access the section in codebehind

Tags: asp.net

I have tried with field value

```
<sc:fieldrenderer fieldname="field" runat="server"/>
```

I am able to get the field value but I need to access the section that contains number of fields 
What is the way to achieve that?

Comment: <sc:fieldrenderer fieldname="field" runat="server"/> this the way of access the field in sitecore is there a way for accessing a section this what my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sections are only to get the fields organized so there isn't a control to render all the fields of a section, you have to render field by field.